# Android SlidingTabLayout Selected Tab Typeface Bold

Tags: android

How do I make selected tab's Typeface bold in SlidingTabLayout? I found enough questions on setting the selected tab colour, but none on setting the selected tab Typeface. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed it as follows:

In the `onPageScrolled()` method make the following changes:

```
View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        View leftOfSelected = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position-1);
        View rightOfSelected=null;
        if (position<=tabStripChildCount-1) {
            rightOfSelected = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position + 1);
        }

        if (selectedTitle != null) {
            TextView selectedText = (TextView) selectedTitle;
            TextView leftOfSelectedText = (TextView) leftOfSelected;
            TextView rightOfSelectedText = (TextView) rightOfSelected;
            if (position > 0 && position < tabStripChildCount - 1) {
                selectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                leftOfSelectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                rightOfSelectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            } else if (position == 0) {
                selectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                rightOfSelectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

            } else if (position == tabStripChildCount - 1) {
                selectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                leftOfSelectedText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            }
        }
```

Similarly, the `scrollToTab()` method can be edited with the same code snippet as above. All you need to do is replace `selectedTitle` with `selectedChild` and `position` with `tabIndex`. If you want better UI response, you may also do the same in `onPageSelected()` method. Just remember to re-declare `tabStripChildCount`.

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

With the introduction of TabLayout, this has become easier. Please refer to Alex Zatsepin's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` to your TabLayout with method 
`addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener)`.
And Override methods like this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    LinearLayout tabLayout = (LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) mMainTabs.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
    TextView tabTextView = (TextView) tabLayout.getChildAt(1);
    tabTextView.setTypeface(tabTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    LinearLayout tabLayout = (LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) mMainTabs.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
    TextView tabTextView = (TextView) tabLayout.getChildAt(1);
    tabTextView.setTypeface(tabTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
```

Comment: Thanks! This has become real easy with the introduction of TabLayout. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Alexey How to ensure that the default selected Tab is also bolden? It looks like the addOnTabSelectedListener is called after the view is shown so the default selected tab doesn't call that method

Comment: @saintjab just add listener before start adding tabs

Answer (score 1):

In your **SlidingTabLayout.java**, you can see **createDefaultTabView(Context context)** function, this is where you can set custom typeface:

```
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.main));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}
```

**setTypeface** is situated in the 5th line of the above snippet

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I've tried it before. It sets all tabs' Typeface as bold. I need only the selected tab's Typeface bold. Thanks anyway :)